# Codeigniter form validation breaks json value

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Hey I'm submiting an array on post where each value is a json string, like this :

```
Array
(

    [destinations] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"selected_value":185,"destinations":38709,"type":"cl","name":"name1"}
            [1] => {"selected_value":395,"destinations":28867,"type":"cl","name":"name2"}
        )

)
```

Now when I decode it :

```
    foreach($destinations as $json){
            $row = json_decode($json,true);
   ...
  }
```

It works fine, however if I try and run form validation on the destinations :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('destinations', 'Destinations', 'required');
```

I can no longer `json_decode` the value, tough it seems to be fine, if I echo it I can see :

```
{"selected_value":395,"destinations":28867,"type":"cl","name":"name2"}
```

But the decode doesn't work and `$row` is null.

Running `json_last_error` gives : 4
and var_dump of `$json` gives :

```
string(143)
 "{"selected_value":185,"destinations":38709,"type":"cl","name":"07h00 תקינים"}"
```

**Note:** the name values are in hebrew, I gave an example in english so easier to read.

I've tried working around it by creating a custom callback function because I thought the implemntation of required is the problem, but I got same results.
Does anyone know this bug or/and how can it be fixed?
I know I can just check it regullary but I would rather use CI's form validation.
I'm using codeigniter 2.1.3, without an option to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the json_last_error function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php. It may help you what in discovering what the error is. Also try doing a var_dump on the variable and post it here.

Comment: This should be a comment, and I've wrote it, "But the decode doesn't work and $row is null."

Comment: Running the json_last_error function after the $row = json_decode($json,true); row will help you in discovering the error.

Comment: You have a malformed json equivalent to this constant JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.

Comment: Try doing a var_dump on the $json variable inside that foreach loop and post it here.

Comment: Now I know the reason. json_decode only works with UTF-8 encoded strings. Your string is I think UTF-16 encoded as seen in the name property of the json.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that form validation is applied only on post data which is not found. You can do the alternative like this

```
$row = json_decode($json,true);

$_POST['destinations'] = $row['destinations'];
```

And now

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('destinations', 'Destinations', 'required');
```

This should work.

Comment: Form validation runs before I try and decode it, that decoding is proccessing only if data is found. $json is an element in $_POST['destinations'], I failed to understand your solution...

Comment: You should see the answer of @HashemQolami. also your question is vague is got `destinations` from inside json

Comment: I didn't see no answer of  @HashemQolami , and my question is a simplification, the array $destinations is the $_POST['destinations']...

Comment: he has deleted the answer. Use array in form validation rule `$this->form_validation->set_rules('destinations[]', 'Destinations', 'required');` [Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields)

Comment: I have changed it, still same result.